# printing to windows console degrees (°) and cube symbol (³)

Tags: c++, windows, console, cout

I'm working on a c++ windows console program and I need to print degrees (°) and cube symbol (³).

There's tons of info on the ° and the only way that worked for me was:

```
cout << value << "\370 C" << endl;
```

Now, what terminology is this? I need the same thing for ³.
I've read somewhere that \370 is octal code, but I can not find any relevant chart with it mentioned that way, or with any equivalent for ³.

Comment: `\370` == 248 == 0xF8.  Somebody named "Bruno" would likely be using [this code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).  So you are looking for `\374`.  Don't hesitate to try them all btw.

Comment: Perfect, Hans. Thank you very much.

Comment: See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: The relevant chart for a string or character literal is the one you tell your compiler to use as the execution encoding ([-fexec-charset](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) or [/execution-charset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708818.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
cout << value << (char)176 << " C" << endl;
```

with the number which is parsed to char being the decimal representation of an ascii sign.

³ should be 0xB3 in hexadecimal, 179 in decimal

For more, wacht [this](http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easier and use [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Using Unicode you don't need to explicitly encode non-ASCII characters, you just include them in your source as-is. This also makes your program independent from the code page of the console, which could be different in another country.

Steps needed:

- Save your source file in a Unicode encoding (UTF-8 works well, UTF-16 works too but some version control software have issues with the latter).
- At the beginning of your program, call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` once. This switches the standard output to UTF-16 encoding. UTF-16 is the preferred Windows encoding as the OS uses it internally, so no conversion overhead will occur.
- Use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` everywhere. Never mix both.
- Always use wide (UTF-16) [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) via the `L` prefix.
- Make sure that a console font is selected that actually includes these symbols (very likely as these are quite common).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    // Switch stdout encoding to UTF-16.
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    // Output UTF-16 string literal.
    std::wcout << L"°³" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "°" and "³" have glyphs in all of the commonly used console fonts. The major downside to the console window is that it doesn't use Uniscribe or DirectWrite, which would support automatic fallback fonts and complex scripts.

Comment: @eryksun You are right. I wrote my answer so it could also be applied to the more general case of displaying *any* Unicode character.

Comment: That's what the second sentence of my comment addresses. Unfortunately the console can't *display* any Unicode character. Rendering is limited to non-complex scripts in the basic multilingual plane, and most fonts only cover a relatively small subset up to a few thousand glyphs. But even if text renders incorrectly or as the default character for the selected font (e.g. a boxed question mark), we can still copy and paste it to another window.